How to handle html table in react i18n?
I am having table structure with the text. I want to localize it using react-i18next.
Using Trans, it supports basic html tags like . However, I am having email template as follows:
<table><tr><td>Hello User</td></tr><tr><td>Please visit the site for exclusive offers</td></tr></table>
I don't want to separate out table and text. I want it in translation.json itself. Is there any way out to achieve this kind of scenario in i18n?

Just supply your HTML tags to the Trans component. Where the key in the component object matches the HTML tag within your translation JSON. Modify as you see fit.
<Trans i18nKey="yourKey" components={{table: <table></table>, tr: <tr></tr>, td: <td></td>}}/>

